# Custom sort Python list with certain strings always at beginning?

Tags: python

I am working in Python 2.7. I have a list of strings like this:

```
mylist = ['is_local', 'quantity_123', 'actual_cost_456', 
         'actual_cost_123', 'quantity_456', 'total_items_123', 
         'id', 'total_items_456', 'name', 'postcode']
```

The list will always have the `id`, `name`, `postcode` and `is_local` fields in it, but the other fields will vary.

I would like to sort the list so that it always starts with the set fields above, and then has the other fields in alphabetical order.

For example:

```
mylist.sort(custom_sort)
print mylist
['id', 'name', 'postcode', 'is_local', 'actual_cost_123', 
 'actual_cost_456', 'quantity_123', 'quantity_456' ...]
```

My problem is how to define the `custom_sort` function. I've tried this:

```
def custom_sort(a, b):
  if a == 'id':
    return 1
  elif a == 'name':
    return 1
  elif a == 'postcode':
    return 1
  elif a == 'is_dispensing':
    return 1
  elif a > b:
    return 1
  else:
    return -1
```

But then `mylist.sort(custom_sort)` gives me an error: `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not duplicate elements within `mylist` you can use `set.difference` method to get the difference between the custom list with `mylist` then sort and append it to your custom list :

```
>>> l=['id', 'name', 'postcode', 'is_local']
>>> l+sorted(set(mylist).difference(l))
['id', 'name', 'postcode', 'is_local', 'actual_cost_123', 'actual_cost_456', 'quantity_123', 'quantity_456', 'total_items_123', 'total_items_456']
>>>
```

Else you can use a list comprehension :

```
>>> l+sorted([i for i in mylist if not i in l])
['id', 'name', 'postcode', 'is_local', 'actual_cost_123', 'actual_cost_456', 'quantity_123', 'quantity_456', 'total_items_123', 'total_items_456']
>>>
```